# JavaFx ScrollPaneSkin cannot be cast to ScrollPane

Tags: javafx, fxml, classcastexception, scrollpane

Recently I am working on JavaFx and i am try to make some complex design layout. The design concept is that when i click a Button an ***AnchorPane*** Dynamically load inside of a ***ScrollPane***

---

***Here is my code***

```
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/com/rahadur/view/FXMLDocument.fxml"));
        AnchorPane pane = (AnchorPane)loader.load();

         /* HERE IS THE PROBLEM FAILD TO CONVERT SCROLLPANE */
        ScrollPane scroll_pane = (ScrollPane) btn_add_click.getParent().getParent();

        Node node = scroll_pane.getContent();
        node = null;
        scroll_pane.setContent(pane);
```

---

The problem is that when the code try to covert **ScrollPane** from parent Class it's show me this ***Error***

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ScrollPaneSkin$4 cannot be cast to javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane
```

i search many time but did not find any solution for this problem. hope you guy give me a batter solution

Thanks for review this problem...

Comment: what is btn_add_click?

Comment: "btn_add_click"  is the child button of AnchorPane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the combination of `getChildren()` and `getParent()` methods to traverse the scene graph is not so reliable and appropriate. Give the `fx:id` to some most used nodes and get them by `lookup()` :

In fxml file

```
<ScrollPane fx:id="scrollpane"  ... >
```

In backend class

```
ScrollPane scroll_pane = (ScrollPane) scene.lookup("#scrollpane");
scroll_pane.setContent(anchorpane);
```

Comment: thank you so much.. your solution is work.. :) i would like to Follow you. how can i communicate with you.

Comment: @Rahadur, you can always get the support and help from the community, just continue to post the questions to here and they will get answered eventually. Pay attention to ask good formatted, well structured questions, to able to get more attention from the community.